# Get form element's label/value pairs from &$form or &$form_state

Tags: 7, forms

I need to pass an array with all the fields (with their values) from a form from the submit function to a rules_invoke_event.

to do this I'm calling a get_fields() function, in this function I have acces to the form and form_state objects. Just wondering how I could loop through one of these with a foreach to get an array with the pairs?

```
function get_fields($form, $form_state)
  $fields = array()
  foreach(element in form)
  { 
    $fields[$element[key]] = element[value];
  }
  return$ fields
}
```

something like this but with correct syntax?

Help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work.

```
function get_fields_this_step($form_state) {
    $fields = array();
    foreach($form_state['values'] as $key=>$value){
        $fields[$key] = $value;
    }
    unset($value);
    return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very close, simply dpm($form_state) (if you have Devel Module installed) or print_r it. You'll find there all the form values you're needing. Loop over the array that contains form values inside the $form_state array.

Answer (score -1):

Or you can just use

`$form_state['values']['submitted_tree']`

which is already formatted in the way you want. I'm not sure if this only applies to forms created with the webform module, but worth a shot!

Comment: This doesn't seem to return anything on my end. Where did you get this from?